# I forgot my spending pin number. Is there anyway I can get around it to get my bitcoin?

Tags: wallet-recovery

I forgot my spending pin number, is there anyway I can get around this?

Comment: As anoncoin said in the answer, we could use a bit more information to actually be able to answer this. What software or wallet are you using? Are your funds in a custodial or self-custodial setup?

Answer (score 1):

"Spending PIN"s aren't a feature of Bitcoin; if you are keeping your bitcoin in a self-custody wallet like Bitcoin Core, all you need to spend your bitcoin is access to the wallet file itself (or your seed phrase to regenerate it). If you encrypted the wallet file, you will need your password; this cannot be circumvented, as the whole point of the encryption is to keep people out who get your wallet file off your computer but don't know the password.

Judging by calling it a PIN and not a password though, I think you bought Bitcoin at an exchange like Coinbase, Bitfinex, or Kucoin and did not withdraw it to your own wallet, instead letting the exchange keep it in the account you have with them. **Not knowing which exchange you used, I cannot speculate on their exact processes; you will need to contact your exchange's customer support about any problems with your account with them, such as a forgotten PIN.**